# Hiding and Showing Tabs in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a simple interface with Tabs on the left and an image that's sliding on the right. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to hide the old image (stored in the div) and show the new one in a clean way. I've posted the HTML and jQuery below. Any thoughts would be appreciated

```
 var resource_box = $('.resource-box')
  resource_box.find('div').not('.selected').each(function(){
    $(this).css('display', 'none'); // Hides all the Content for Each UL
  });

  var tabs = $('.names ul');
  $('.names ul li').click(function () {
      tabs.find('li').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('selected')
      });
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var tabId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.resource_box').find(tabId)


  });

<div class="container gallery-container">

      <div class="names">
        <ul>
          <li id="vector-icon-packs" class="selected">Vector Icon Packs</li>
          <li id="user-interface-kit">User Interface Kits</li>
          <li id="vector-illustrations">Vector Illustrations</li>
          <li id="high-res-textures">High-Res Textures</li>
          <li id="premium-brushes">Premium Brushes</li>
          <li id="print-templates">Print Templates</li>
          <li id="mockups">Mockups</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="grid items resource-box">
        <div style="background: url(http://f.cl.ly/items/3A1U223S1A0k47361G1G/icons.png);" id="vector-icon-packs" class="selected"></div>
        <div style="background: url(http://f.cl.ly/items/3A1U223S1A0k47361G1G/icons.png);" id="user-interface-kit"></div>
        <div style="background: url(http://f.cl.ly/items/3A1U223S1A0k47361G1G/icons.png);" id="vector-illustrations"></div>
        <div style="background: url(http://f.cl.ly/items/3A1U223S1A0k47361G1G/icons.png);" id="high-res-textures"></div>
        <div style="background: url(http://f.cl.ly/items/3A1U223S1A0k47361G1G/icons.png);" id="premium-brushes"></div>
        <div style="background: url(http://f.cl.ly/items/3A1U223S1A0k47361G1G/icons.png);" id="print-templates"></div>
        <div style="background: url(http://f.cl.ly/items/3A1U223S1A0k47361G1G/icons.png);" id="mockups"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your elements share ID's, which is not allowed, try this:

```
$('.names ul li').click(function(){
  $('.resource-box div').hide();                      // hides all divs
  $('.resource-box div').eq($(this).index()).show();  // shows correct one
});
```

The key part of the code is `eq($(this).index())`, which grabs the [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) (what number child the list item is) and then uses that to decide which div to show. Of course, this means they have to be in the same order

Comment: You can also chain methods on selected elements to improve perfomance - `$('.resource-box div').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();`